# pip: pulling updates from remote git repository

Tags: python, git, github, pip, scikit-learn

I installed [scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn) from GitHub a couple of weeks ago:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn@master
```

I went to GitHub and there have been several changes to the master branch since then.

How can I update my local installation of `scikit-learn`?

I tried `pip install scikit-learn --upgrade` but I got:

```
Requirement already up-to-date
Cleaning up ...
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`pip` searches for the library in the Python package index. Your version is newer than the newest one in there, so pip won't update it.

You'll have to reinstall from Git:

```
$ pip install git+git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn@main
```

Comment: Thanks. I presume that I need to uninstall the package then first? The odd thing is that pip could in principle remember that I got this from the git repository in first place, right? Is there a design decision behind this?

Comment: @user815423426: Pip will just upgrade the package.

Comment: @user815423426: As for the auto-upgrade, I have no clue. From what I can tell, Pip just packages the module into an egg and installs it. I'm sure it's possible to have it store the download URL somewhere, but I don't personally know if that's just a missing feature or a conscious design choice.

Comment: You don't need to uninstall the package, it will do it itself.

Comment: you don't need the -U flag for upgrade?

Comment: I would strongly recomment to uninstall before re-installing. It occured to me that a newly committed file did not come forward and lost time looking around.

Comment: if you use anaconda, having the git packages in an environment file will allow you to update everything by simply updating the whole environment using the file. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042389/conda-installing-upgrading-directly-from-github/32799944#32799944

Answer (score 22):

You need to install the version from github, or locally.

The way I usually do is that I git clone the repository locally and I run `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py develop` on it so I'm sure about the version being used.

Re-issuing the command you've done the first time with the upgrade flag would do the trick otherwise.:

```
pip install --upgrade git+git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn@main
```

Answer (score 14):

What worked for me was to use `--force-reinstall`:

`pip install --force-reinstall --no-deps git+git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn@main`

`--no-deps` to avoid reinstalling all the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, Pip installs based on pypi. If you want to upgrade to the version that is currently hosted on github, then you are going to have to use the url from github.