# Conda: Installing / upgrading directly from github

Tags: python, github, pip, package-managers, conda

Can I install/upgrade packages from GitHub using [conda](http://www.continuum.io/blog/conda)?

For example, with `pip` I can do:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/scrappy/scrappy@master
```

to install `scrappy` directly from the `master` branch in GitHub. Can I do something equivalent with conda?

If this is not possible, would it make any sense to install pip with conda and manage such local installations with pip?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

There's better support for this now through `conda-env`.  You can, for example, now do:

```
name: sample_env
channels:
dependencies:
   - requests
   - bokeh>=0.10.0
   - pip:
     - "--editable=git+https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk.git@8c0d34291aaafec00e02eaa71cc2a242790a0fcc#egg=facebook_sdk-master"
```

It's still calling pip under the covers, but you can now unify your conda and pip package specifications in a single `environment.yml` file.

If you wanted to update your root environment with this file, you would need to save this to a file (for example, `environment.yml`), then run the command: `conda env update -f environment.yml`.

It's more likely that you would want to create a new environment:

`conda env create -f environment.yml` (changed as supposed in the comments)

Comment: There is some documentation [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-file-manually), but it doesn't explain the `pip` part (just gives an example) but it's pretty self-explanatory. You can also [export an existing conda env to yaml](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#exporting-the-environment-file) (including pip-installs).

Comment: In case you need to install from a subdirectory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566200/how-can-i-install-from-a-git-subdirectory-with-pip
e.g.  - "--editable=git+https://github.com/poleguy/pyshark.git@7fc7fbb400080868291bd7268676f7513f898504#egg=src&subdirectory=src"

Comment: Using `--editable` didn't work, said not found, but removing it worked great. Thanks

Answer (score 164):

The answers are outdated. You simply have to conda install pip and git. Then you can use pip normally:

1. Activate your conda environment `source activate myenv`
2. `conda install git pip`
3. `pip install git+git://github.com/scrappy/scrappy@master`

Comment: Much of  is already in the OP (using `pip install`). The question is asking how to do it using `conda` _directly_, which the top answer provides.

Answer (score 31):

`conda` doesn't support this directly because it installs from binaries, whereas git install would be from source. `conda build` does support recipes that are built from git. On the other hand, if all you want to do is keep up-to-date with the latest and greatest of a package, using pip inside of Anaconda is just fine, or alternately, use `setup.py develop` against a git clone.

Comment: What if your package has a release binary associated with it?

Answer (score 29):

I found a reference to this in [condas issues](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/699). The following should now work.

```
name: sample_env
channels:
dependencies:
   - requests
   - bokeh>=0.10.0
   - pip
   - pip:
     - git+https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk.git
```

Comment: conda will complain if you don't also add pip on a line by itself as a dependency. Furthermore, other useful examples of using conda with pip can be found here: https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/main/tests/conda_env/support/advanced-pip/environment.yml