# Pip install forked github-repo

Tags: python, pip

I'm working on a project and need a little different functionality from the package sklearn. I've forked the repo and pushed my changes. I know that I can install from github via pip:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/wdonahoe/scikit-learn-fork.git@master
```

and then I can install the package with setup.py:

```
python setup.py install
```

However, I am confused about what to do after this step. Running setup.py creates some .egg-info folders and .egg-links files in .../dist-packages/, but I am unsure what to do with them. Ideally, I'd like to go into my project in .../projects/my_project and say something like

```
from sklearn-my-version import <stuff>
```

or switch it out with just

```
from sklearn import <stuff>
```

I am also a little confused because a lot of resources on this issue mention using easy_install, which I thought pip replaced.

Comment: First, you don't want to do both installs on the same package. Either `pip install git+…` or `python setup.py install` (or `pip install .`), not both.

Comment: Meanwhile, either one of those will install the package into your (system, user, or virtualenv) dist-packages or site-packages. (It doesn't go anywhere inside your project. If that's what you think you want, most likely what you actually want is a virtualenv.) You can just `import` the package the same way as any other package. Assuming it installed as `sklearn`, you can just do `from sklearn import <stuff>`, which sounds like exactly what you want to do, so what's the problem?

Comment: Finally, the reason "a lot of resources" mention `easy_install` is that a lot of resources are years out of date. If you're reading old StackOverflow answers, blog posts, printed books, etc., they're unlikely to have been updated since they were initially written.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

try again using just (-e flag lets you git pull updates by installing it as a git repo)

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/wdonahoe/scikit-learn-fork.git@master#egg=scikit-learn
```

more on eggs:
http://mrtopf.de/blog/en/a-small-introduction-to-python-eggs/

Comment: Great hint about the `-e` option!

Comment: Gorgeous general purpose answer.

Comment: When I do this it creates a `/src` to the install in my current directory.  Where is the best place to run these commands from?

Comment: how do I install from an ssh only repo?

Comment: @pythonian29033: This one is outdated, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50141879/5290519

Comment: @lacostenycoder try using a virtual environment. Then the install will put this in `./env/src/...`