# Where Can I find the implemented DQfDAgent?

Tags: python, git, pip, keras-rl

I'm trying to use that Object as [This Blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/lunar-landings-from-demonstrations-27b553b00ce2) uses in [His Code](https://github.com/jakegrigsby/lunarDQfD) but when I do `from rl.agents.dqn import DQfDAgent` it returns me and error `ImportError: cannot import name 'DQfDAgent'`.

I've done a `dir(rl.agents.dqn)` and there is no `DQfDAgent` object so, how has the man of the blog done it?

**(Update 1)**

I've already done this:

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/jakegrigsby/keras-rl.git#egg=keras-rl
```

but it returns this error:

```
Command "git clone -q git://github.com/jakegrigsby/keras-rl.git C:\Users\myuser\src\keras-rl" failed with error code 128 in None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> note that the master version of keras-rl may be missing my additions. See my fork.

Just do a quick search for DQfDAgent and you ll see that it is not in the rl.agents.dqn source code page. Use the branch of the author ([here](https://github.com/jakegrigsby/keras-rl)) to import properly and use the agent he has implemented but which is not in the official version.

Comment: Ouch, my fault. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Np. I missed it too at first . Always happy to help!

Comment: How can I use this version of keras-rl instead of the one I'm using now? I tried to run the setup.py script and I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: i honestly don't know... I will try to look into it and update the answer.
but look at this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292039/pip-install-forked-github-repo) @Angelo

Comment: i suggests that you open a new question because i am not qualified enough in this domain to help you. Plus with an accepted answer less people will see the new issue.

Answer (score 1):

The README.md file of the [repo you linked](https://github.com/jakegrigsby/lunarDQfD) indicates that:

> Note that the master version of keras-rl may be missing my additions. See [my fork](https://github.com/jakegrigsby/keras-rl).

In such a fork, you can find an implementation of DQfDAgent in the following code:
https://github.com/jakegrigsby/keras-rl/blob/master/rl/agents/dqn.py

Comment: Hi Angelo! You probably will get a better response for you new update opening a new question, since this question already has an accepted response.
BTW, don't forget voting up any answer which you found useful.