# Conda uninstall one package and one package only

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

When I try to uninstall `pandas` from my `conda` virtual env, I see that it tries to uninstall more packages as well:

```
$ conda uninstall pandas
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .........

Package plan for package removal in environment /Users/amelio/anaconda/envs/py35:

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    dask-0.7.6                 |           py35_0         276 KB

The following packages will be REMOVED:

    blaze:       0.10.1-py35_0
    odo:         0.5.0-py35_1
    pandas:      0.18.1-np111py35_0
    seaborn:     0.7.0-py35_0
    statsmodels: 0.6.1-np111py35_1

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    dask:        0.10.1-py35_0      --> 0.7.6-py35_0

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

I would like to uninstall `pandas` **only** and not have anything else downgraded.

I understand that there these packages have **dependencies** to `pandas` and even to **specific versions** of pandas, but is this even possible at all with `conda`?

### Partial motivation

My understanding is that it [isn't that easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042389/conda-installing-upgrading-directly-from-github) to install a package from GitHub using `conda`. At least it isn't as easy as using a one-liner as one can do with `pip`.

Since I want to use the version in `master`, my plan is to uninstall the `conda` version and use `pip` to install `pandas` from master on the official repo GitHub.

How can I do this?

Comment: a simple solution would be to just pip install the new version from master over conda's version.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can use `conda remove --force`.

The documentation says:

```
--force               Forces removal of a package without removing packages
                      that depend on it. Using this option will usually
                      leave your environment in a broken and inconsistent
                      state
```

Comment: For me, I was trying to get around all the extra fluff when you run plain `conda remove x` about updates/etc, but I still wanted to remove some dependencies. I was able to do some piping: `conda remove --force -y $(conda list $MATCHING_PATTERN | grep "$MATCHING_PATTERN" | awk '{ print $1 }')` got rid of a package and its dependencies matching `$MATCHING_PATTERN`

Comment: conda remove --force pandas

Comment: unfortunately this isn't possible with `mamba` at the moment: https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba/issues/412