# How to uninstall a single packages in anaconda?

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu, anaconda

I'm trying to uninstall numpy & then install a specific version of it on anaconda. However, the prompt also told that others packages will also uninstall itself. How do I uninstall only numpy packages? I'm using ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: How did you install numpy? The command `conda remove --force numpy` will remove numpy and only numpy from the current environment. See: https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-remove.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conda uninstall one package and one package only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459186/conda-uninstall-one-package-and-one-package-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you anaconda contain `pip` tool, you can uninstall numpy only through `pip uninstall numpy`