# `conda install` reporting failure to find package that `conda search` finds?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm getting this error when attempting to install a package:

```
(pybert-tst)
dbanas@Davids-MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects/PyBERT
$ conda install -c dbanas pybert
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: failed


UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pybert
Use "conda search <package> --info" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

But, I see the `pybert` package when I search:

```
(pybert-tst)
dbanas@Davids-MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects/PyBERT
$ conda search -c dbanas pybert --info
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Loading channels: done
pybert 3.1.0 pyh7b7c402_2
-------------------------
file name   : pybert-3.1.0-pyh7b7c402_2.tar.bz2
name        : pybert
version     : 3.1.0
build       : pyh7b7c402_2
build number: 2
size        : 235 KB
license     : BSD License
subdir      : noarch
url         : https://conda.anaconda.org/dbanas/noarch/pybert-3.1.0-pyh7b7c402_2.tar.bz2
md5         : 9537824117ffca8bd024f74cd0f44c7a
timestamp   : 2019-07-16 22:18:08 UTC
dependencies:
  - chaco
  - docutils
  - enable
  - jinja2
  - kiwisolver
  - numpy
  - pygments
  - pyibis-ami >=3.0.0
  - python >=3.7.0,<3.8
  - scikit-rf
  - scipy
  - sphinx
  - traits
  - traitsui
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Just a guess, but I think if you check the dependencies for the two packages you may find that they require different versions of the same package. This can be solved by using virtual environments

Comment: @Hugh_Kelley, thanks for replying! Sorry, which two packages are you referring to?

Comment: sorry, I think actually if you run `conda list` you'll see `pybert` is already installed. To install it from another source you'll have to `conda uninstall pybert` and then run your original line. Conda won't just replace an existing package. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459186/conda-uninstall-one-package-and-one-package-only if there's a problem uninstalling. Depending on exactly what you're trying to do it may be easier to use `pip`

Comment: and to clarify, that error message is specifying a conflict, not that it can't find the module per the title.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by two dependencies of the `pybert` package being locked to Python 2.7, while Python itself was calling for Python 3.7.

I sure would've been nice to have seen the names of those two other packages in the error message. :(