# conda won't install package that shows up in search

Tags: r, arm, conda

This is similar to the question [`conda install` reporting failure to find package that `conda search` finds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066414/conda-install-reporting-failure-to-find-package-that-conda-search-finds), but I am confident that the root cause is different as the cause of that problem was due to incompatible dependencies, whereas here I am trying to install the same version of a package that I already have, from a different channel.

Running `conda search conda-forge/osx-arm64::r-base` will result in:

```
# Name                         Version    Build       Channel
[... multiple other versions]
r-base                         4.2.1      hab92f3e_2  conda-forge         
r-base                         4.2.1      hd4fed26_0  conda-forge         
r-base                         4.2.1      hd4fed26_1  conda-forge
```

`conda list r-base` gives:

```
# Name                    Version              Build         Channel
r-base                    4.2.1                h85fa70c_1    conda-forge
```

So as you can see, I already have this file installed.  However, my Mac's architecture is arm (verified with `uname -p`) and my R version says "Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)" so I want to swap to the `conda-forge/osx-arm64` channel in the hopes of changing it.  (Since I think this mismatch is the root cause of another problem I'm experiencing).

However, `conda install conda-forge/osx-arm64::r-base` returns a PackageNotFoundError.

Now, I think I know why - when I run `conda info`, I get:

```
conda version : 22.9.0
conda-build version : 3.21.5
[...]
virtual packages : __osx=10.16=0
                   __unix=0=0
                   __archspec=1=x86_64
[...]
platform : osx-64
```

Thus, my conda distribution seems to think I have an x86.  I think the reason why is that I used to use an x86 on an old computer which I have since transferred all its data to my new one.  I suspect that conda thinks that it can only install x86-specific packages, which is problematic.  However I have no idea how to change this.

---

For your convenience, the full output of `conda info` is listed here:

```
    active environment : JupyterWithR
    active env location : /Users/baileyandrew/opt/anaconda3/envs/JupyterWithR
            shell level : 2
       user config file : /Users/baileyandrew/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/baileyandrew/.condarc
          conda version : 22.9.0
    conda-build version : 3.21.5
         python version : 3.9.7.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=10.16=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /Users/baileyandrew/opt/anaconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /Users/baileyandrew/opt/anaconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/baileyandrew/opt/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/baileyandrew/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/baileyandrew/opt/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/baileyandrew/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/22.9.0 requests/2.26.0 CPython/3.9.7 Darwin/21.3.0 OSX/10.16
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS lets one run **osx-64** binaries in emulation, and since you transferred the **base** Conda installation, that’s likely what it is. You can still create **osx-arm64** environments by setting the `subdir` environment variable, which is what controls the folder searched on Anaconda Cloud. For example,

```bash
## create empty environment 
conda create -n r42_arm

## always activate before installing
conda activate -n r42_arm

## configure its subdir
conda config —-env —-set subdir osx-arm64

## install R and enable usage as kernel
conda install r-base=4.2 r-irkernel
```

Please note that many packages are still not built natively for **osx-arm64**. So, it might be a smoother user experience to continue working with **osx-64** for now. Particular native builds can be requested following the [documented procedure](https://conda-forge.org/docs/maintainer/knowledge_base.html#apple-silicon-builds).