# How delete anaconda-project downloaded files?

Tags: anaconda

After I have run

```
anaconda-project add-packages python=3.5
```

there downloaded some dependencies.
Where those downloading locate in? and How could I delete those files by anaconda command line?

Answer (score 0):

If you had created a virtual environment, then you can find the location of the packages by

```
$ echo $VIRTUAL_ENV
```

The packages are stored inside lib/ directory. You can delete the files manually or use [`conda remove --force`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38463294/8568784)

Comment: It's not corresponding to the same question.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is, anaconda-project run under a installed env, it will install the absent packges in this env by default.