# conda uninstall pandas removes more than conda install pandas adds

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, conda

I just ran conda remove pandas and got this huge list of packages which were removed.

The following packages will be REMOVED:

```
  _anaconda_depends-2020.07-py37_0
  alabaster-0.7.12-py37_0
  anaconda-custom-py37_1
  anaconda-client-1.7.2-py37_0
  anaconda-project-0.8.4-py_0
  argh-0.26.2-py37_0
  asn1crypto-1.4.0-py_0
  astroid-2.4.2-py37_0
  astropy-4.0.1.post1-py37he774522_1
  atomicwrites-1.4.0-py_0
  autopep8-1.5.4-py_0
  babel-2.8.0-py_0
  backports-1.0-py_2
  backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-py37_2
  bcrypt-3.1.7-py37he774522_1
  beautifulsoup4-4.9.1-py37_0
  bitarray-1.4.2-py37he774522_0
  bkcharts-0.2-py37_0
  blas-1.0-mkl
  blosc-1.19.0-h7bd577a_0
  bokeh-2.1.1-py37_0
  boto-2.49.0-py37_0
  bottleneck-1.3.2-py37h2a96729_1
  brotlipy-0.7.0-py37he774522_1000
  bzip2-1.0.8-he774522_0
  cffi-1.14.0-py37h7a1dbc1_0
  cftime-1.2.1-py37h2a96729_0
  chardet-3.0.4-py37_1003
  cloudpickle-1.5.0-py_0
  clyent-1.2.2-py37_1
  colorcet-2.0.2-py_0
  comtypes-1.1.7-py37_1001
  contextlib2-0.6.0.post1-py_0
  cryptography-2.9.2-py37h7a1dbc1_0
  curl-7.71.1-h2a8f88b_1
  cycler-0.10.0-py37_0
  cython-0.29.21-py37ha925a31_0
  cytoolz-0.10.1-py37he774522_0
  dask-2.20.0-py_0
  dask-core-2.20.0-py_0
  datashader-0.11.0-py_0
  datashape-0.5.4-py37_1
  diff-match-patch-20200713-py_0
  distributed-2.20.0-py37_0
  docutils-0.16-py37_1
  et_xmlfile-1.0.1-py_1001
  fastcache-1.1.0-py37he774522_0
  fastparquet-0.3.2-py37h2a96729_0
  filelock-3.0.12-py_0
  flake8-3.8.3-py_0
  flask-1.1.2-py_0
  freetype-2.10.2-hd328e21_0
  fsspec-0.7.4-py_0
  future-0.18.2-py37_1
  get_terminal_size-1.0.0-h38e98db_0
  gevent-20.6.2-py37he774522_0
  glob2-0.7-py_0
  gmpy2-2.0.8-py37h0964b28_3
  greenlet-0.4.16-py37he774522_0
  h5py-2.10.0-py37h5e291fa_0
  hdf4-4.2.13-h712560f_2
  hdf5-1.10.4-h7ebc959_0
  heapdict-1.0.1-py_0
  holoviews-1.13.3-py_0
  holoviz-0.11.3-py_0
  html5lib-1.1-py_0
  hvplot-0.6.0-py_1
  icc_rt-2019.0.0-h0cc432a_1
  icu-58.2-ha925a31_3
  idna-2.10-py_0
  imageio-2.9.0-py_0
  imagesize-1.2.0-py_0
  intel-openmp-2020.1-216
  intervaltree-3.0.2-py_1
  isort-4.3.21-py37_0
  itsdangerous-1.1.0-py37_0
  jdcal-1.4.1-py_0
  joblib-0.16.0-py_0
  jpeg-9b-hb83a4c4_2
  json5-0.9.5-py_0
  jupyter-1.0.0-py37_7
  jupyter_console-6.1.0-py_0
  jupyterlab-2.1.5-py_0
  jupyterlab_server-1.2.0-py_0
  keyring-21.2.1-py37_0
  kiwisolver-1.2.0-py37h74a9793_0
  krb5-1.18.2-hc04afaa_0
  lazy-object-proxy-1.4.3-py37he774522_0
  libarchive-3.4.2-h5e25573_0
  libcurl-7.71.1-h2a8f88b_1
  libiconv-1.15-h1df5818_7
  liblief-0.10.1-ha925a31_0
  libllvm9-9.0.1-h21ff451_0
  libnetcdf-4.7.3-h1302dcc_0
  libpng-1.6.37-h2a8f88b_0
  libspatialindex-1.9.3-h33f27b4_0
  libssh2-1.9.0-h7a1dbc1_1
  libtiff-4.1.0-h56a325e_1
  libxml2-2.9.10-h464c3ec_1
  libxslt-1.1.34-he774522_0
  llvmlite-0.30.0-py37ha925a31_0
  locket-0.2.0-py37_1
  lxml-4.5.2-py37h1350720_0
  lz4-c-1.9.2-h62dcd97_1
  lzo-2.10-he774522_2
  markdown-3.1.1-py37_0
  matplotlib-3.0.3-py37hc8f65d3_0
  matplotlib-base-3.2.2-py37h64f37c6_0
  mccabe-0.6.1-py37_1
  menuinst-1.4.16-py37he774522_1
  mkl-2020.1-216
  mkl-service-2.3.0-py37hb782905_0
  mkl_fft-1.1.0-py37h45dec08_0
  mkl_random-1.1.1-py37h47e9c7a_0
  mock-4.0.2-py_0
  more-itertools-8.4.0-py_0
  mpc-1.1.0-h7edee0f_1
  mpfr-4.0.2-h62dcd97_1
  mpir-3.0.0-hec2e145_1
  mpmath-1.1.0-py37_0
  msgpack-python-1.0.0-py37h74a9793_1
  multipledispatch-0.6.0-py37_0
  netcdf4-1.5.3-py37h012c1a0_0
  networkx-2.4-py_1
  nltk-3.5-py_0
  nose-1.3.7-py37_1004
  numba-0.46.0-py37hf9181ef_0
  numexpr-2.7.1-py37h25d0782_0
  numpy-1.19.1-py37h5510c5b_0
  numpy-base-1.19.1-py37ha3acd2a_0
  numpydoc-1.1.0-py_0
  olefile-0.46-py37_0
  openpyxl-3.0.4-py_0
  pandas-0.24.2-py37he350917_1
  panel-0.9.7-py_0
  param-1.9.3-py_0
  paramiko-2.7.1-py_0
  partd-1.1.0-py_0
  path-14.0.1-py37_0
  path.py-12.0.2-py_0
  pathlib2-2.3.5-py37_1
  pathtools-0.1.2-py_1
  patsy-0.5.1-py37_0
  pep8-1.7.1-py37_0
  pexpect-4.8.0-py37_1
  phantomjs-2.1.1-1
  pillow-7.2.0-py37hcc1f983_0
  pkginfo-1.5.0.1-py37_0
  pluggy-0.13.1-py37_0
  ply-3.11-py37_0
  prompt_toolkit-3.0.5-0
  psutil-5.7.0-py37he774522_0
  py-1.9.0-py_0
  py-lief-0.10.1-py37ha925a31_0
  pycodestyle-2.6.0-py_0
  pycosat-0.6.3-py37he774522_0
  pycparser-2.20-py_2
  pycrypto-2.6.1-py37he774522_10
  pyct-0.4.6-py37_0
  pycurl-7.43.0.5-py37h7a1dbc1_0
  pydocstyle-5.0.2-py_0
  pyflakes-2.2.0-py_0
  pylint-2.5.3-py37_0
  pynacl-1.4.0-py37h62dcd97_1
  pyodbc-4.0.30-py37ha925a31_0
  pyopenssl-19.1.0-py_1
  pyqt-5.9.2-py37h6538335_2
  pyreadline-2.1-py37_1
  pysocks-1.7.1-py37_1
  pytables-3.6.1-py37h1da0976_0
  pytest-5.4.3-py37_0
  python-jsonrpc-server-0.3.4-py_1
  python-language-server-0.34.1-py37_0
  python-libarchive-c-2.9-py_0
  python-snappy-0.5.4-py37ha925a31_0
  pyviz_comms-0.7.6-py_0
  pywavelets-1.1.1-py37he774522_0
  pywin32-ctypes-0.2.0-py37_1001
  pyyaml-5.3.1-py37he774522_1
  qdarkstyle-2.8.1-py_0
  qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0
  qtawesome-0.7.2-py_0
  qtconsole-4.7.5-py_0
  qtpy-1.9.0-py_0
  regex-2020.6.8-py37he774522_0
  requests-2.24.0-py_0
  rope-0.17.0-py_0
  rtree-0.9.4-py37h21ff451_1
  ruamel_yaml-0.15.87-py37he774522_1
  scikit-image-0.16.2-py37h47e9c7a_0
  scikit-learn-0.23.1-py37h25d0782_0
  scipy-1.5.0-py37h9439919_0
  seaborn-0.10.1-py_0
  selenium-3.141.0-py37hfa6e2cd_1001
  simplegeneric-0.8.1-py37_2
  singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py37_0
  sip-4.19.8-py37h6538335_0
  snappy-1.1.8-h33f27b4_0
  snowballstemmer-2.0.0-py_0
  sortedcollections-1.2.1-py_0
  sortedcontainers-2.2.2-py_0
  soupsieve-2.0.1-py_0
  sphinx-3.1.2-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-1.0-py37_1
  sphinxcontrib-applehelp-1.0.2-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-devhelp-1.0.2-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp-1.0.3-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-jsmath-1.0.1-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-qthelp-1.0.3-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml-1.1.4-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-websupport-1.2.3-py_0
  spyder-4.1.4-py37_0
  spyder-kernels-1.9.2-py37_0
  sqlalchemy-1.3.18-py37he774522_0
  statsmodels-0.11.1-py37he774522_0
  streamz-0.5.4-py_0
  sympy-1.6.1-py37_0
  tbb-2020.0-h74a9793_0
  tblib-1.6.0-py_0
  threadpoolctl-2.1.0-pyh5ca1d4c_0
  thrift-0.13.0-py37ha925a31_0
  tk-8.6.10-he774522_0
  toml-0.10.1-py_0
  toolz-0.10.0-py_0
  tqdm-4.47.0-py_0
  typed-ast-1.4.1-py37he774522_0
  typing_extensions-3.7.4.2-py_0
  ujson-1.35-py37hfa6e2cd_0
  unicodecsv-0.14.1-py37_0
  urllib3-1.25.9-py_0
  watchdog-0.10.3-py37_0
  werkzeug-1.0.1-py_0
  win_inet_pton-1.1.0-py37_0
  win_unicode_console-0.5-py37_0
  wrapt-1.11.2-py37he774522_0
  xarray-0.11.3-py37_0
  xlrd-1.2.0-py37_0
  xlsxwriter-1.2.9-py_0
  xlwings-0.19.5-py37_0
  xlwt-1.3.0-py37_0
  xz-5.2.5-h62dcd97_0
  yaml-0.2.5-he774522_0
  yapf-0.30.0-py_0
  zict-2.0.0-py_0
  zope-1.0-py37_1
  zope.event-4.4-py37_0
  zope.interface-4.7.1-py37he774522_0
  zstd-1.4.5-h04227a9_0
```

When I then do conda install pandas, I get a tiny list of packages...for example it didnt reinstall xlsxwriter, which I was maybe assuming it needs to write Excel files.  Why is this, and how do I get back all these packages through a pandas install?

This is what got added back in on a conda install pandas.

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  blas               pkgs/main/win-64::blas-1.0-mkl
  intel-openmp       pkgs/main/win-64::intel-openmp-2020.1-216
  mkl                pkgs/main/win-64::mkl-2020.1-216
  mkl-service        pkgs/main/win-64::mkl-service-2.3.0-py37hb782905_0
  mkl_fft            pkgs/main/win-64::mkl_fft-1.1.0-py37h45dec08_0
  mkl_random         pkgs/main/win-64::mkl_random-1.1.1-py37h47e9c7a_0
  numpy              pkgs/main/win-64::numpy-1.19.1-py37h5510c5b_0
  numpy-base         pkgs/main/win-64::numpy-base-1.19.1-py37ha3acd2a_0
  pandas             pkgs/main/win-64::pandas-1.0.5-py37h47e9c7a_0
```

Comment: In the first case, could it be removing all the packages which depend, directly or indirectly, on Pandas?

Comment: @AMC makes sense.  Can I shove this directly into a requirements.txt file and reinstall via conda?

Comment: Shove the list of removed packages? Some tweaks will be necessary, I think. All you really need is to reinstall the top-level packages, let Conda handle the dependencies. You can find a bit more information on specifying dependencies and creating environments from a file [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file).

Comment: @AMC going to try this http://blog.rtwilson.com/conda-revisions-letting-you-rollback-to-a-previous-version-of-your-environment/

Comment: Ok! It might still be worth considering creating a new environment anyway. It's the perfect opportunity to see if you can get rid of any dependencies, for example.

Comment: You should have selected `N` for `No`. Conda removes all dependencies when removing a package. You might want to just uninstall anaconda and install the new distribution with  python 3.8. Also see [Conda uninstall one package and one package only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38459186)

Comment: Thanks, if I dont miss them I guess I never needed them