# Fipy nominally installed but fipy.test() fails with error messages

Tags: python, fipy

I'm attempting to get FiPy set up using Miniconda 2 on a Windows 7 system, and got to the point of running the test suite with the [recommended](http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/USAGE.html#testing-fipy) `python -c "import fipy; fipy.test()"`.

Unfortunately rather than getting test results, the suite gave me an error with stack trace:

```
running egg_info
creating c:\users\bram\appdata\local\temp\tmpbzt0mv\FiPy.egg-info
writing c:\users\bram\appdata\local\temp\tmpbzt0mv\FiPy.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to c:\users\bram\appdata\local\temp\tmpbzt0mv\FiPy.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to c:\users\bram\appdata\local\temp\tmpbzt0mv\FiPy.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'c:\users\bram\appdata\local\temp\tmpbzt0mv\FiPy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'c:\users\bram\appdata\local\temp\tmpbzt0mv\FiPy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'c:\users\bram\appdata\local\temp\tmpbzt0mv\FiPy.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
running test
running build_ext
fipy version 3.1.3
numpy version 1.12.0
pysparse is not installed
scipy version 0.18.1
matplotlib is not installed
gist is not installed
mpi4py is not installed
mpi4py is not installed
enthought.mayavi is not installed
gmsh is not installed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Users\Bram\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\fipy\__init__.py", line 164, in test
    cmdclass={'test': _TestClass(_test)})
  File "D:\Users\Bram\Miniconda2\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "D:\Users\Bram\Miniconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "D:\Users\Bram\Miniconda2\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "D:\Users\Bram\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg\setuptools\command\test.py", line 172, in run
  File "D:\Users\Bram\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\fipy\tests\testClass.py", line 236, in run_tests
    testLoader = loader_class()
  File "D:\Users\Bram\Miniconda2\lib\unittest\main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "D:\Users\Bram\Miniconda2\lib\unittest\main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "D:\Users\Bram\Miniconda2\lib\unittest\main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "D:\Users\Bram\Miniconda2\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 130, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "D:\Users\Bram\Miniconda2\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 100, in loadTestsFromName
    parent, obj = obj, getattr(obj, part)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'testFiPy'
```

Can anyone help me get this to work?  I don't know where to start with this outcome.

Comment: Is this a pip installed version of FiPy? If so, maybe try cloning from the [main repository](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy) instead and install from the develop branch.

Comment: It was a pip-installed version.  The other recommended install process stops itself, apparently because it can't find dependencies.  Your suggestion appears to have worked, at least as far as getting the test to run.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add for those who (like me) are new to git and conda - to install the FiPy from develop branch you should (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50141879) answer):

1. Activate your conda environment: `source activate myenv` (or `activate
   myenv` for windows)
2. Install git and pip: `conda install git pip`
3. Install FiPy: `pip install git+git://github.com/usnistgov/fipy@develop`