# Cannot install usaddress-scourgify

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I am new to python, and trying to clean addresses. I found the package usaddress-scourgify
https://github.com/GreenBuildingRegistry/usaddress-scourgify

I have installed usaddress in anaconda prompt using pip install.
when I try to do the same for usaddress-scourgify, it gets hung up on "collecting usaddress-scourgify"

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What are your thoughts on this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if [usaddress-scourgify](https://github.com/GreenBuildingRegistry/usaddress-scourgify) is available in anaconda's package repo, you can search for it [here](https://anaconda.org/search?q=usaddress). I would just install it using `pip install usaddress-scourgify`.

However, you can use conda to update/install packages directly from Github, just add it to your `environment.yml` file. [More on that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042389/conda-installing-upgrading-directly-from-github).