# Syntax error when calling github package in anaconda

Tags: python, github, anaconda

I get a syntax error when I try to use the bandcamp-dl package from github to download a full-album. Please note I am using Anaconda with Python 3 on Windows.

To install the package in Anaconda, I followed the instructions from
[Conda: Installing / upgrading directly from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042389/conda-installing-upgrading-directly-from-github)

1. Activate your conda environment `source activate myenv`
2. `conda install git pip`
3. `pip install git+git://github.com/iheanyi/bandcamp-dl`

Next I followed the instructions in the wiki to download a full -album
https://github.com/iheanyi/bandcamp-dl/wiki/How-To-Use-%22For-Dummies%22

4. `bandcamp-dl https://sdoggingsworth.bandcamp.com/album/snacks-hugs-and-rock-n-roll`

I run the following code in anaconda prompt.

```py
import bandcamp_dl
bandcamp-dl https://sdoggingsworth.bandcamp.com/album/snacks-hugs-and-rock-n-roll
```

and get this syntax error

> bandcamp-dl https://sdoggingsworth.bandcamp.com/album/snacks-hugs-and-rock-n-roll
>     File "", line 1
>       bandcamp-dl https://sdoggingsworth.bandcamp.com/album/snacks-hugs-and-rock-n-roll
>                       ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Issue: Full album is supposed to download but I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to run this inside a python file. It is a command-line utility, not a library. From the [github page](https://github.com/iheanyi/bandcamp-dl#description):

> bandcamp-dl is a small command-line app to download audio from BandCamp.com. It requires the Python interpreter, version 3.4 (or higher) and is not platform specific.

It needs python to run, but should not be run from a python file. 
Use your command-line to run

```
bandcamp-dl https://sdoggingsworth.bandcamp.com/album/snacks-hugs-and-rock-n-roll
```

and it should work

Comment: Awesome, that works now when I run it in Anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You tryed this ?

```
bandcamp-dl 'https://sdoggingsworth.bandcamp.com/album/snacks-hugs-and-rock-n-roll'
```

Around hyperlink with quotes