# Installing a package from git in Anaconda environment which is afterwards not recognized in Python

Tags: python, git, pip, package

I'm trying to install a python package directly from github. In my case that's [SciANN](https://github.com/sciann/sciann). When I selected my environment in conda using `conda activate myenv` and afterwards install this package as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50141879) post using the following lines of code:

```
conda install git pip
pip install git+git://github.com/sciann/sciann.git
```

it is successfully installed and I get the message "Successfully built SciANN" in the end of the insatllation procedure. When I then open spyder and type `import sciann` I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sciann'`. I also tried to use `pip3` instead of `pip` but this did not change something.

Have I missed something? Is this package now installed correctly into my environment `myenv`?

Comment: Your `spyder` uses a different Python. `pip` installs the package to one Python but the `spyder` runs with another and cannot access packages installed for the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deleted answer from [Jay Prakash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13807610/jay-prakash) together with the comments brought me on track. Yes there can be different versions of packages installed. So in my case `SciANN` was installed using `pip` as they currently do not offer a `conda` installation while all my other packages where installed with `conda`. I ended up having two different versions of tensorflow installed, one from `pip` and one from `conda` so I deleted one. Additionally I used Python version 3.7 while this package supports only up to 3.6. *And I had to use a non official tensorflow version because my CPU does not support AVX which is a whole new topic.*