# Package updates from remote git repository are not reflected in site-packages

Tags: python, git, pip, conda, package-managers

I have been trying to upgrade a package based off of the most recent changes on git but the changes aren't taking effect. I ran several variations of this command, such as also using `python -m pip` and the actual path to the pip version in anaconda, as well as adding --upgrade: `pip install git+git://github.com/lmcinnes/umap@master`

Here is the output each time:

```
Collecting git+git://github.com/lmcinnes/umap@master
  Cloning git://github.com/lmcinnes/umap (to revision master) to /tmp/pip-req-build-bck1u0of
  Running command git clone -q git://github.com/lmcinnes/umap /tmp/pip-req-build-bck1u0of
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17 in /home/himani/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from umap-learn==0.5.1) (1.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.22 in /home/himani/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from umap-learn==0.5.1) (0.23.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0 in /home/himani/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from umap-learn==0.5.1) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numba>=0.49 in /home/himani/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from umap-learn==0.5.1) (0.51.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pynndescent>=0.5 in /home/himani/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from umap-learn==0.5.1) (0.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: llvmlite<0.35,>=0.34.0.dev0 in /home/himani/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from numba>=0.49->umap-learn==0.5.1) (0.34.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/himani/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from numba>=0.49->umap-learn==0.5.1) (52.0.0.post20210125)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in /home/himani/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pynndescent>=0.5->umap-learn==0.5.1) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /home/himani/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn>=0.22->umap-learn==0.5.1) (2.1.0)
```

And looking in the actual directory of where umap is in site-packages, I can see that none of the files are being changed to reflect the updates, so it seems that nothing is happening. I am tempted to just manually change the files myself but I know that wouldn't be smart for the long run.

Comment: Duplicate: [Conda: Installing / upgrading directly from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042389/conda-installing-upgrading-directly-from-github) Also, I strongly encourage using a new env rather than mutating **base**. Conda-Pip integration is not well-defined, and you don't want to break **base**, which would break your Conda installation as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the `--update` and `--force-reinstall` options of `pip`, or:

`pip install --update --force-reinstall git+git://github.com/lcminnes/umap@master`

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried running with the --upgrade flag also. Just tried it again with -U and still did not work. Got the same output about all requirements being satisfied, and no update to the package files.

Comment: I have also added the `--force-reinstall` option, kindly see the updated answer