# How to install custom packages from GitLab registry in conda.yaml

Tags: anaconda, pypi

I have created a custom python package on a GitLab repository, which I can **successfully install** with the following pip command in a local terminal (terms with `<>` represent variables that need to be replaced before running the command):

```sh
pip install <packagename> --extra-index-url https://<access_token_name>:<access_token>@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/24/packages/pypi/simple
```

However, my **constraint** is that I need to install this package from an anaconda environment created with a `conda.yaml` file. An example of this file is shown below.

```sh
name: test
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - pip
  - pip:
    - pandas==1.2.4
    - numpy==1.20.2
```

**My question**: How do I add the custom package to the `conda.yaml`? It seems that the `conda.yaml` allows to specify dependencies in the format `<packagename>==<package_version>` but it does not allow for custom `pip install` commands like the one above.

**What I have tried** I tried adding `- "--extra-index-url https://<access_token_name>:<access_token>@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/24/packages/pypi/simple"` to the dependencies (as an item under `- pip:`) and could then successfully create a conda environment with `conda env create -f conda.yaml`, i.e. this command was executed without error message. However, my package `<packagename>` did not actually get installed, i.e. it was not listed in `conda list` and it was not possible to import the package (after activating the new environment).

Answer (score 1):

It appears you can resolve this issue by adding git as a dependency before using a git link. So in your case, your test.yaml would look like:

```
name: test
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - git
  - pip
  - pip:
    - git+https://{access_token_name}:{access_token}@gitlab.com/{your_gitlab_username}/{repository_name}.git
```

I was having the same issue with gitlab until I stumbled across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042389/conda-installing-upgrading-directly-from-github) which nudged me into this direction. This works with github links as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add your git package by just providing `git+https://{access_token_name}:{access_token}@gitlab.com/{your_gitlab_username}/{repository_name}.git` in the yaml file.

**test.yaml**

```
name: test
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - pip
  - pip:
    - git+https://{access_token_name}:{access_token}@gitlab.com/{your_gitlab_username}/{repository_name}.git
```

Then run:

```
conda env create --file=test.yaml
```