# Install python package by anaconda prompt from GitHub

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I am trying install the following python package (https://github.com/MikeHughesKent/PyHoloscope/tree/main) from Github by cond!

I tried the steps recommended in this question [Conda: Installing / upgrading directly from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042389/conda-installing-upgrading-directly-from-github), but the following error was rising up ((ERROR: Cannot unpack file C:\Users\Houssain\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-8mqg2pwl\PyHoloscope.git (downloaded from C:\Users\Houssain\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-i98m27z2, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format

ERROR: Cannot determine archive format of C:\Users\Houssain\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-i98m27z2))

please any recommendation to install this package?

Comment: **1**. You cannot install packages from Git repositories using `conda`; conda requires its own special package format. You need `pip` for this. **2**. But not in your particular case — the repository doesn't provide `pyproject.toml`, `setup.cfg` or `setup.py` and hence it's not `pip`-installable either. **3**. Ask the author [at GitHub](https://github.com/MikeHughesKent/PyHoloscope/issues) or [mail list](https://groups.google.com/g/pyholoscope).